# MODULE NOT FOUND IN NEXT JS

Tags: mongodb, next.js, server, server-side-rendering

./pages/api/products.js:3:1
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/models/Product'
1 | import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
2 |  import mongoose from "mongoose";

> 3 |  import {Product} from "@/models/Product";
> | ^
> 4 |  import mongooseConnect from "@/lib/mongoose";
> 5 |
> 6 | export default async function handle (req, res){

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.